# AJAX login with custom 'password' field

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I'm attempting to authenticate users via an AJAX POST request, passing two fields:

```
"email" (required|string|max:255|unique:users)
"password" (required|min:4)
```

`"password"` is being treated as a 4-digit pin code.

I've tried updating `app\Http\Controllers\Auth\Registercontroller.php` to change minimum length to 4 from 6.

My ajax request currently looks like this:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('email', emailStr);
formData.append('password', pin);

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/login",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        success: function (response) {

            console.log('success');

        },
        error: function (jqXHR) {
            var response = $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
            if(response.message) {
                alert(response.message);
            }
        }
});
```

PHP:
app\Http\Controllers\Auth\Registercontroller.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'email' => 'required|string|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:4',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {

        return User::create([
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

app\Http\Controllers\Auth\Logincontroller.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class LoginController extends Controller
{



    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/profile';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        if ($request->ajax()){

//            $user = auth()->user();
//            $user->update([
//                'last_login_at' => Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString()
//            ]);
//            $user->last_login_at = new DateTime;
//            $user->save();

            return response()->json([
                'auth' => auth()->check(),
                'user' => $user,
                'intended' => $this->redirectPath(),
            ]);

        }
    }

}
```

I'm receiving a 500 "The given data was invalid." message.

Comment: Could you please include your php code too?

Comment: The PHP is Laravel's default make:auth fascade (Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth)

Comment: try to pass 6 digits and see if you still get the error

Comment: But it is the PHP code that is causing the 500 error, so we need to see that

Comment: @GiacomoMasseroniChiaro still getting a 500 "The given data was invalid." message.

Comment: are you adding CSRF token to the ajax call?

Comment: @GiacomoMasseroniChiaro no; do I need to?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I just added Register and Login controllers in Laravel.

Comment: @zstardust225 you need the token in all your POST request

Comment: @GiacomoMasseroniChiaro is there a preferred method in integrating this?

Comment: @GiacomoMasseroniChiaro I've included a hidden input field with value={{ csrf_token }}" and set headers in $.ajaxSetup to 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content'), same error.

Answer (score 0):

in html

```
<head>
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</head>
```

in script

```
$.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });


$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/login",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: $('#form_id').serialize(),
        cache: false,
        success: function (response) {

            console.log('success');

        },
        error: function (jqXHR) {
            var response = $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
            if(response.message) {
                alert(response.message);
            }
        }
});
```

Comment: The data from this page is being validated correctly via a custom controller I wrote; it's the step after this that isn't (when I pass email and password to Laravel's /login auth fascade...

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the more specific error message on each input, using this Controller code :

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    // this will return error response when request is invalid
    $this->validate($data, [
        'email' => 'required|string|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:4',
    ]);

    // this will executed only if the request is valid
    return response()->json([
        'message' => "Data validated!"
    ]);
}
```

And this ajax code :

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('email', emailStr);
formData.append('password', pin);

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/login",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        success: function (response) {

            console.log(response.message);

        },
        error: function (jqXHR) {
            console.log(jqXHR.responseJSON);
            console.log(jqXHR.responseJSON.message);
            // this will display errors on each request data
            $.each(jqXHR.responseJSON.errors, function (i, error) {
                console.log(i, " : ", error[0]);
            });
        }
});
```